# WebRTC: How can I make my system reliable for 5.000 to 10.000 users for 1-on-1 video chat

Tags: webrtc

I have implemented a 1-on-1 videochat with WebRTC.

I'm currently using "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" and "turn:numb.viagenie.ca".

The WebRTC code runs on my own server.

Since there is no way to emulate 5.000 to 10.000 users, I would like to ask here what steps might be necessary to ensure that no quality problems due to bandwidth or lack of capabilities or similar occur.

I have not even been able to find reliable information about how many users my server can handle.

And I didn't find any information about this on the net.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently using "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" and "turn:numb.viagenie.ca".

I would double check your TURN is working! I have seen quite a few people using that and no relay candidates are emitted. You aren't going to get an error if auth failed, just no candidate will be emitted!

> Since there is no way to emulate 5.000 to 10.000 users

Companies exist already that do this (testRtc) or you can roll your own with something like Pion WebRTC, aiortc or GStreamer. I would do E2E testing, spin up a bunch of WebRTC clients and see what fails :)

Comment: Would it be better to configure my own server as a TURN server?

Comment: Also, can you recommend a way to make my approach reliable? If I use testRtc and see that it fails, then I don't know a way to avoid the problem, or do I?

Comment: I would run your own server, or pay a provider. I am biased I work for a company that has hosted TURN (AWS), I would evaluate all your options! Twillio, Xirsys (and a few other ones)

Comment: Since you want to test a large distributed system I don't have any advice on how to break down the problem more sorry. You can unit test individual pieces, but the advantage of TestRTC is that it E2E and is real world scenarios.